How to create a Wear OS complication with a progress dot
I've used the RANGED_VALUE complication type to successfully show something like the digital time or step progress complications in the attached image.
But I'm wondering if there's a variant that shows the dot moving along an arc as seen in the built-in weather complication on the Pixel Watch (both the circle on the left, and the expanded version in the top right), or if this requires a custom renderer?

